# Force Slider to slide after callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidesjs

Hi I have a slider image gallery built with slides.js. The slider works pretty well but I need to implement swipe functionality. To get it I've thought to make a swipe callback with Hammer.js and make a function to force the slider to slide the image to the next one or the previous one. But I don't know if Slides.js has this option. What I want to do would be something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    var touchControl = new Hammer(listItems[0]);
    touchControl.on("panright", function(event) {
      // Here is what I'm not sure how to do it
      $("slider").slide
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean call back function? it's in the doc.

Comment: I know. But I mean that I need when swipe gesture is on, the image of the slider slides to the next image

Comment: instead of  $("slider").slide(), can't you fake a click event? $(".slider").click();

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I've done to make it work

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var item = document.getElementsByClassName("flexslider");
  var touchControl = new Hammer(item[0]);
  touchControl.on("panright", function(event) {
    if (event.distance > 250) {
      $(".flexslider").flexslider("prev");
    }        
  });
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var item = document.getElementsByClassName("flexslider");
  var touchControl = new Hammer(item[0]);
  touchControl.on("panleft", function(event) {
    console.log(event.distance)
    if (event.distance > 250) {
      $(".flexslider").flexslider("next"); 
    }       
  });
});
```